# Convert Javascript object to C# object

Tags: javascript, c#, facebook

I'm setting up facebook canvas payments and it requires a callback when an order is successful. I have the code below and I'm using ajax to pass the callback data to my method so I can do something with it. I just don't know what to set as the parameter for the method so that I can pass the data correctly.

```
FB.ui(obj, function (data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "/Home/finishOrder",
                    data: myjsobject,
                    async: true
                });
            });

public class orderDetails
    {
        public string payment_id { get; set; }
        public decimal amount { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string request_id { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string signed_request { get; set; }
    }

    public void finishOrder(orderDetails orderDetails)
    {
        SendEmail.sendEmail(orderDetails.amount.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: If this is MVC or WebAPI, the parameter should be orderDetails class in C#. The framework will automatically bind the same named properties from your JSON to your C# object. Also, if you specify data, dataType and contentType in your Ajax call then you don't need to set the queryatring manually *and* jQuery will automatically serialize your JavaScript object to json

Comment: This is MVC and I changed the parameter to orderDetails and it now returns null and I'm using the same properties as the facebook documentation @SteveLillis

Comment: Then set it to orderDetails again, name it myOrderDetails (model binding might be getting confused by the word data if its used elsewhere in the framework) and update your Ajax to specify data and content type instead of querystring.

Comment: @SteveLillis I updated my code above but I don't think I'm doing it correctly because everytime I change something, it still gets passed as null

Comment: remove "order=" from your url and add "data: thejsobjectthatrepresentsorder" to the ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but try this:

```
FB.ui(obj, function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                Content-type: "application/json",
                url: "/Home/finishOrder",
                data: myjsobject,
                success: function(data) { alert('success'); }
            });
        });

public class orderDetails
{
    public string payment_id { get; set; }
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string request_id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string signed_request { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult finishOrder(orderDetails orderDetails)
{
    SendEmail.sendEmail(orderDetails.amount.ToString());
    return Json(new { Result = "e-mail sent" }, JsonBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Note: the JS object must have the same property names as the C# one.

Comment: I tried this but it isn't even calling the method now. I also don't understand why you have named the line data: myjsobject. Shouldn't that be changed to orderDetails?   @SteveLillis

Comment: Sorry, it was to indicate it should be the JavaScript object you want to send to server. Probably the data from FB?

Comment: I'm not sending any data to the server. It is just a callback function to let me know that the payment was successful.

Comment: Then where are you trying to get the amount from?

Comment: I made some changes and I figured it out